# Are Lipschitz functions almost continuously differentiable in practice?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, continuity, analytic-functions

[Despite being common to have a continuous function that is not a differentiable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function#Density_of_nowhere-differentiable_functions), in engineering and applied mathematics, it's quite common to have non-differentiable functions that are related to analytic functions, like semianalytic functions. Such type of functions satisfies stronger properties than the continuous functions, like the [Lojasiewicz inequality](https://people.orie.cornell.edu/aslewis/publications/07-lojasiewicz.pdf).

Thinking on applications, for a semianalytic, see [Definition 2.1.](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1988__67__5_0.pdf) (or subanalytic, see [Definition 3.1.](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1988__67__5_0.pdf)), Lipschitz continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, my question is whether a "weak notion of continuity of the derivative" (given ahead in (*)) holds for such types of functions. Expressly, defining the set of differentiable points of $f$ ([which has full measure in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem)) as $\Delta_{f}$, I want to know if, for all $x^{*} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and all $ \epsilon > 0$, there exist $ \delta > 0 $ such that for all $y^{*} \in B(x^{*},\delta)$ it holds
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\Delta \to 0} \  \inf \{ \|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \| : \\ x \in \Delta_{f} \cap B(x^{*};\Delta)\setminus\{x^{*}\} \text{ and } y \in \Delta_{f} \cap B(y^{*};\Delta)\setminus\{y^{*}\} \} <\epsilon \tag{*}
\end{align}$$

Note that, when the function is locally Fréchet differentiable with locally continuous derivative, this is true since it reduces to the continuity of the derivative. Also, It seems to be true for all subanalytic functions.

> $$\text{Is the notion of continuity in (*) true for subanalytic or semianalytic functions?}$$

Comment: Was that $\liminf_{ \begin{array}{l} x \overset{\Delta_{f}}{\to} x^{*} \\ y \overset{\Delta_{f}}{\to} y^{*} \end{array}}$ supposed to be $\liminf_{ \begin{array}{l} {\Delta_{f}}\ni x{\to} x^{*} \\ {\Delta_{f}}\ni y{\to} y^{*} \end{array}}$?

Comment: Please define the terms you use. We can't read 4 papers to answer the question!

Comment: The definitions are in the Definition 2.1. and 3.1. I also deleted an expression to avoid confusion

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with the Lipschitz condition - definable functions in any o-minimal structure are differentiable almost everywhere they're defined and their partial derivatives (where they exist) are again definable functions. Since subanalytic functions are definable functions in an o-minimal structure, there you go.

Comment: "This doesn't really have anything to do with the Lipschitz condition". This what? I'm not interested in knowing that the function is differentiable almost everywhere, since I have it due to the Lipschitz condition. I want to know the condition associated with $(*)$ is true in this case.

Comment: Let $f$ be a Lipschitz functions between Euclidean spaces (or from an open domain in one to another Euclidean space). Theorem: Given arbitrary eps>0, there is a $C^1$ function $g$ (between same spaces) and a subset of the domain of measure at most eps such that f coincides with $g$ at every point outside this marginal subset. See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS9Wgkdvok4 This is called sometimes the Lusin or C^1-Lusin property. It follows from Rademacher's theorem plus generic Lusin and Egorov theorem. Not sure if your (*) follows.

Comment: @Behnam Esmayli Wow! I think this is enough to prove what I want! I will think about it a bit, but any positive (or negative) answer will be accepted as immediately, if it is done here.

Comment: It is indeed very powerful. BTW, I left out a very deep result needed in the proof. Other than the above, you need to apply Whitney's theorem. Although proofs without Whitney also exist.

Comment: I need a proper reference for your result, with the statment clearly stated. A book or even an article are possible refences.

Comment: Evans and Gariepy: Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions. It has the proof too. Analogous result for Sobolev functions also givenin seperate sections.

Comment: Pretty beautiful book. The Theorem you said is stated at THEOREM 6.11 in the Revised Edition version of the book. I liked the notation of the book and the way the author minimally can state the theorems, but yet make proofs succinct and complete. I have a presentation to do and my thesis to revise, as soon I got an answer, I will put it here. It's not hard to see that (*) is true for the Lipschitz functions using THEOREM 6.11.

Comment: It is a great book.

Comment: This is also proved in Leon Simons GMT notes you can find freely on the web on page 42.